# I want select records from two table. And I want to write query for that, but I'm unable to write

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table one contains updated_at (can be more than one row) datetime And second contains started_date and stopped_date(one or more records).

I want select updated_at date which should not in between started_date and stopped_date.

Thanks in advance.

I saw the other Question "Check overlap of date ranges in MySQL".

But this not what I want.

user_location 

`+---+-----+-----+---------------------+
|id | lat | lon | updated_date        |
+---+-----+-----+---------------------+
| 1 |16.45|75.45|2018-01-09 12:50:57  |
| 2 |16.85|75.15|2018-01-09 12:53:45  |
| 3 |16.78|75.25|2018-01-09 12:55:48  |
| 4 |16.43|75.35|2018-01-09 13:57:35  |
| 5 |16.48|75.47|2018-01-09 14:59:30  |
| 6 |16.49|75.49|2018-01-10 05:59:58  |
| 7 |16.50|75.50|2018-01-10 07:35:15  |
+---+-----+-----+---------------------+`

location_blocked_datetime

`+---+--------------------+---------------------+
|id |     start_date     |  stopped_date       |
+---+--------------------+---------------------+
| 1 |2018-01-09 05:55:48 | 2018-01-09 07:55:48 |
| 2 |2018-01-09 12:51:48 | 2018-01-09 12:56:48 |
| 3 |2018-01-10 04:30:48 | 2018-01-04 06:55:48 |
+---+--------------------+---------------------+`

I want select location from user_location table where updated_date should not be there in start_date and stopped_date.start_date and stopped dates are not fixed and contain more than 1 records

The result of above query should look like this:-

If I want to select locations On 2018-01-09

**Result Of Above Query**

`+---+-----+-----+---------------------+
|id | lat | lon | updated_date        |
+---+-----+-----+---------------------+
| 1 |16.45|75.45|2018-01-09 12:50:57  |
| 2 |16.43|75.35|2018-01-09 13:57:35  |
| 3 |16.48|75.47|2018-01-09 14:59:30  |
+---+-----+-----+---------------------+`

Comment: If you can't figure it out from the duplicate link, come back here, paste your query into the question and someone can reopen.

Comment: SO is not a *write code for me site*

Comment: @Jens But sadly it feels that way to me much of the time :-(

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen MeToo ;(

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen I have edited above question can you check it once.

Comment: Where is your query?